# how to async resize and save image in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to resize and save asynchronously a batch of downloaded images. What is the best approach to do this?

Currently I call this method after downloading the image:

```
    public void SaveToResizedBitmap(Bitmap pBitmap, int pWidth, int pHeight, string pOutputFileNameStr)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image origImage = pBitmap;
        System.Drawing.Image origThumbnail = new Bitmap(pWidth, pHeight, origImage.PixelFormat);

        Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(origThumbnail);
        oGraphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        oGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        oGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        Rectangle oRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight);
        oGraphic.DrawImage(origImage, oRectangle);

        string lLowerFileNameStr = pOutputFileNameStr.ToLower();
        if (lLowerFileNameStr.Contains(".png"))
        {
            // Save the file in PNG format
            origThumbnail.Save(pOutputFileNameStr, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        if (lLowerFileNameStr.Contains(".jpg"))
        {
            // Save the file in JPG format
            origThumbnail.Save(pOutputFileNameStr, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        origImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Is there a way to do this asynchronously?

Comment: There is nothing really asynchronous operation here, You can use  `Task.Run` to delegate it to threadpool. btw you ought to dispose `oGraphic` instance.

Comment: If all you want is just to make UI responsible during saving, use Task.Run as @SriramSakthivel said.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks for your comment, I will try Task.Run. I was hoping there were Async solutions resizing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of images to process, a producer/consumer pattern might be better than starting a Task for each image. Put your data in a BlockingCollection, and start a long running Task which retrieves the data with bc.GetConsumingEnumerable() and processes them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will look into this (have never used this before).